# Attempt to set a non-existent setting when `emcc -s ONLY_MY_CODE`

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm currently learning WASM, and have been following [Google's tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/web-assembly-intro/index.html#2), and it told me to use the following command:

```
  -s WASM=1 -s ONLY_MY_CODE=1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_board_init','_board_ref','_board_step']" \
  -o output.js *.c
```

However, I got the error prompt:

```
emcc: error: Attempt to set a non-existent setting: 'ONLY_MY_CODE'
 - perhaps a typo in emcc's  -s X=Y  notation?
 - (see src/settings.js for valid values)
```

Version:
emcc: 2.0.1

OS:
Mac OS

---

Actually the above is the first issue I encountered which probably led to another one. I run the command without the option `-s ONLY_MY_CODE`, then I load and instantiate .wasm in js file. After running the web page I got another error message from the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" function="emscripten_resize_heap" error: function import requires a callable
```

Hope anyone experienced in WASM can give me some insights.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

After [emcc v1.38.47](https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/release_notes.html), the ONLY_MY_CODE option is no longer supported.
Use STANDALONE_WASM instead.

I guess the following code should work for you;

```
-s WASM=1 -s STANDALONE_WASM -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="'_board_init','_board_ref','_board_step']"  -o output.js *.c
```